# Only the top track in NLA editor is playing even though none of the tracks are favorited?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

[This is the link to my Blender 3.2 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n3YiKjBTY6LX-MKwlOfYn8U9RD4VHND3/view?usp=sharing) which has three Mixamo animations, [T-pose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-pose) to running, and then picking up. Even though they are all in different tracks only the top one is playing and if I try to play another track I have to start them but that leads to the top track not playing anymore? How do I fix this so I can blend my animations?

Answer (score 2):

Im trying to understand your problem but as you haven't posted any screenshots its a bit hard. But ill try to recommend some common solutions:

- Check if every NLA Strip is active
- Set the Extrapolation on each pushed down Animation to "nothing" as it will overwrite everything beneath the "hold" NLA Stip.
- Check if Blending in and out are reaching over the next NLA-Strip, if yes, shorten

Hope this will help, let me know!

[image]

Comment: Thankyou that really helped

Comment: @Chemreaction why not give him an upvote if it was helpful? :)

Comment: This helped me. I am new to blender and did not know that the Extrapolation mode had to be set to "Nothing". I upvoted this.